# Image carouselwith React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, image, carousel

How about the community? I have a problem with the implementation of an image carousel, when I was not using React it worked perfectly. Now that I'm migrating the page to React I have an error.

**
This is the home page where the carousel is:
**

```
const Inicio = () => {
  return (

    <div>
      <section id="imagenes1">
        <div className="row sub-carousel">
          <div className="col-lg-6" >
            <h1>Soluciones informáticas y seguridad Electrónica</h1>
          </div>
          <div className="col-lg-6">
            <div id="carouselExampleFade" className="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-bs-ride="carousel">
              <div className="carousel-inner">
                <div className="carousel-item active">
                  <img className="border-img-carousel d-block " src={pc1} width="900" height="400" alt="Computadoras" />
                </div>
                <div className="carousel-item">
                  <img className=" border-img-carousel d-block  " src={camara1} width="900" height="400" alt="Redes informáticas" />
                </div>
                <div className="carousel-item">
                  <img className=" border-img-carousel d-block " src={redes1} width="900" height="400" alt="Seguridad Electronica" />
                </div>
              </div>

              <button className="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleFade" data-bs-slide="prev">
                <span className="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span className="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
              </button>
              <button className="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleFade" data-bs-slide="next">
                <span className="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span className="visually-hidden">Next</span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

    
      <section id="clients">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row  row-clients">
            <div className="col-lg-12">
              <h2 className="title-product-h2">Nuestros clientes</h2>
              <div className="carrusel">
                <div className="carrusel-items">

                  <div className="carrusel-item">
                    <img src={LogoOntario} alt="Ontario-inmobiliaria"/>
                  </div>

                  <div className="carrusel-item">
                    <img src={LogoAsa} alt="Cooperativa-ASA"/>
                  </div>

                  <div className="carrusel-item">
                    <img src={LogoToulouse} alt="TOULOUSE HOTELES"/>
                  </div>

                  <div className="carrusel-item">
                    <img src={LogoUmari} alt="Umari-siente-la-amazonia"/>
                  </div>

                  <div className="carrusel-item">
                    <img src={LogoTusanwok} alt="Tusan-wok"/>
                  </div>

                  <div className="carrusel-item">
                    <img src={LogoActo} alt="Acto-restobar"/>
                  </div>

                  <div className="carrusel-item">
                    <img src={LogoAdrenalina} alt="Adrenalina-panoramico"/>
                  </div>

                  <div className="carrusel-item">
                    <img src={LogoVinosmajestad} alt="Vinos Majestad"/>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Inicio
```

This is the Component that I am using so that the carousel passes the images automatically and returns.

Compiled with problems:
×
ERROR
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'scrollWidth')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'scrollWidth')

I want a prompt response from someone in the community who can help me and thus continue studying for my project.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Where are you accessing `scrollWidth`?

Comment: const carrusel = document.querySelector(".carrusel-items");
let maxScrollLeft = carrusel.scrollWidth - carrusel.clientWidth;

Comment: The carousel is on the home page, on that page it imports the Carousel components where its functions are.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you're using `document.querySelector(".myclass")` which returns an array, thus to access anything in it you'll have to use a specific index like `[0]` (the first match on the page) or loop through all the matches in the case that you have multiple carousels on the same page.

So your code would be something like (if there's only one carousel on the page):

```
const carrusel = document.querySelector(".carrusel-items");
let maxScrollLeft = carrusel[0].scrollWidth - carrusel[0].clientWidth;
```